# Passing c-style strings into a c library in C++ (md4c)

Tags: c++, c, markdown

I'm trying to implement [md4c](https://github.com/mity/md4c) into a C++ program I'm writing.
It offers an markdown to html method in its md4c-html header, here's its documentation:

> To convert a Markdown input, call md_html() function. It takes the Markdown input and calls the provided callback function. The callback is fed with chunks of the HTML output. Typical callback implementation just appends the chunks into a buffer or writes them to a file.

Essentially, you pass it a c-style string, the length of the string and a method it can output its results to, along with a few flags and pointers to additional optional data.

I'm not very well practiced with C as a language but I created the below code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "Libs/md4c-html.h"

#define MD4C_USE_UTF8

void SaveTextToFile(const MD_CHAR* text, MD_SIZE size, void* unneeded)
{
    std::string fileUrl = "../../outputfile.html";

    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(fileUrl, std::ios_base::app);
    file << text;
    file.close();

    text = 0;
}


int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("../../inputfile.md");

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();

    file.close();

    std::string text = buffer.str();
    int length = text.length();

    int endCode = md_html(text.c_str(), length, SaveTextToFile, NULL, 0, 1);
    printf("program finished with code %i\n", endCode);
}
```

This outputs some really odd results where it parses the entire document between every tag. For example, this

```
# header1
paragraph
```

becomes this:

```html
<h1>header1
paragraph
</h1>
<p>paragraph
</p>
```

I've spent a while stepping through the code trying to work out the problem and its a bit beyond me, but md4c is a widely used library so I'm inclined to think the issue is how I'm using it rather than the library itself.

Is there anything obviously wrong I'm doing that a C programmer would notice?

Comment: Pedantic side note; `printf("program finished with code %i\n", endCode);` is misinformation, since the program doesn't actually `return endCode;` from `main()`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I put that there since my compiled code wasnt outputting the resulting value from `md_html` when I returned it. I guess it should really say `md_html finished, returning %i`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but from the signature of `SaveTextToFile` I'm guessing `text` is not nul-terminated and so `file << text` walks off the end of the string into undefined behavior.  Use `file.write(text, size)` instead.

Comment: @MilesBudnek std::string's c_str() is required to return a nul-terminated buffer. See : [std::string::c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) : *returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string.*

Comment: @PepijnKramer I mean the other `text`.  The one that's passed to `SaveTextToFile` and is the result of processing some portion of the `text` in `main`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: the c-library provides the argument, and even for sub-string, size is important, as input cannot be modified.

Comment: I suspect that `#define MD4C_USE_UTF8` should come **before** the `#include "Libs/md4c-html.h"`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing  `std::ofstream file; file.open(fileUrl, std::ios_base::app);` to `std::ofstream file(fileUrl, std::ios_base::app);`, and similarly for the input stream. Also, you don't have to call `file.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Comment: @Evansnye_ " Is there anything obviously wrong I'm doing that a C programmer would notice?" --> `std::string fileUrl = "../../outputfile.html";` is invalid C code.  Snice posted code is invalid C, best to remove C tag and edit question accordingly.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, you've misunderstood me a bit, the library is a c library and I'm trying to use it with c++. The parameters the api takes in are heavy c stuff that I dont recognize from c++ so I felt like it would be a good idea to get some C developers opinions

Comment: Note that `int length = text.length();` may differ from `strlen(text.c_str())` concerning _null characters_ and lengths > INT_MAX.

Comment: I would prefix `SaveTextToFile` with `extern "C"`. This might affect results on some platforms; but before that, you must read the doc on `md_html` to confirm the expected calling-convention for the callback.

Comment: Everything else aside, if you're "'trying to implement md4c into a C++ program" please tell us the reason for it. Why are you trying to reimplement it? What is the actual problem that the existing C program doesn't solve for you? How would a reimplementation in C++ solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all the responses!

I posted a message on the repo's issues in the end and my problem was that I was assuming the string was null terminated. It isnt! Instead you have to use size to know how much to output.

Instead it was printing all the strings stored in memory together till it found the null terminator in my original data!

Comment: Don't post an answer saying you've posted a message somewhere off site but post the answer here. And no "thank you"s are necessary epecially not in an answer.